# Does there exists a "local slice" for an action $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on $ \operatorname{Spf}(\widehat{A}) $ (char zero)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, formal-groups, formal-schemes

Every action $ \beta $ of $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $ on a variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ over a field of characteristic zero is obtained from a locally nilpotent derivation $ \delta $ via $ f(t_{0} \ast x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\delta^{j}(f)(x)t_{0}^{j})/j! $.  In this case, the existence of a local slice is equivalent to the existence of $ g,h \in A $ such that $ \delta(g)=h $ and $ h \in A^{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $.

Such a pair of polynomials always exists in characteristic zero.  However, suppose that we now move to the category of formal schemes and possibly non-algebraic actions $ \beta $ of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on affine formal schemes $ \operatorname{Spf}(\widehat{A}) $.  In this case, the action $ \beta $ is obtained from a derivation $ \delta \in \Omega_{\widehat{A}/k} $ via $ f(t_{0} \ast x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (\delta^{j}(f)(x)t_{0}^{j})/j! $.  Note that the derivation $ \delta $ may not be locally nilpotent so the co-action $ \beta^{\sharp}: \widehat{A} \to \widehat{A}[[t]] $.  Also the action may not be algebraic.  Does there exist a pair of $ g,h \in \widehat{A} $ such that $ \delta(g)=h $ and $ h \in \widehat{A}^{\widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}}} $?